# Proper way to bind two collections to the control in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a class, that have two collections of different types of items. I want to bind the class collections to the TreeView. What is proper way to organize ViewModel?

Below is my guess.

Model:

```
public CClassModel
{
    List<A> m_itemsA;
    List<B> m_ItemsB;
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public CClassViewModel
{
    CClassModel = m_model;
    ObservableCollection<object> m_items;
    public CClassViewModel
    {
        m_model = new CClassModel();
        m_items = Merge(m_model.m_itemsA, m_model.m_itemsB);
    }
}
```

Binding:

```
<TreeListControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.m_items}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a suggestion, it's useful use an `Interface` in case like this. If `A` and `B` share some property, then you could do something like this:

```
public interface IAB
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class A:IAB
{
    public string Name { get;  set; }
}
public class B:IAB
{
    public string Name { get;  set; }
}
```

With this design your `CClassModel` class would be like this:

```
public clas CClassModel
{
  public List<IAB> Items{ get;  set; }

  //...
}
```

Now, another thing that I suggest you is create a `ViewModelBase` abstract class:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Property Changed Event Handler
    protected void SetPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion Property Changed Event Handler
}
```

This abstract class will help you to define a new ViewModel when you need it, for example:

```
public class MainViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<IAB> _collection;
    public ObservableCollection<IAB> Collection
    {
        get { return _collection; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._collection)
                _collection = value;
            SetPropertyChanged("Collection");
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var m_model = new CClassModel();
        Collection=new ObservableCollection<IAB>(m_model.Items);
    }
}
```

As @Rafal said, to bind you need to create public properties in your ViewModel, this way you are going to expose the info that you want to bind.

One thing that is possible to achieve using the MVVM pattern is zero code behind relative to your Views. As you can see, the instantiation of the ViewModel is in the same View, especifically in the `Resources`. To use that instance, you need to set the `DataContext` property of your root control (in this case for example is a Grid). Now you can use the properties that you have defined in your ViewModel as I show below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wpfApplication2="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <wpfApplication2:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}">
    <TreeView x:Name="ABTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"> </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

To bind you need to have public property, currently you have private filed.

use

```
public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
ObservableCollection<object> m_items;
```

Comment: I may be unclear, but the question is how to bind two collections to the control together.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
public class A
{ 
  // add something usefull
}

public class B
{
  // add something usefull
}

public class CClassModel
{
  public List<A> m_ItemsA;
  public List<B> m_ItemsB;
}

public class APlaceHolder
{
  public string NodeName { get; set; }
  public List<A> Items { get; set; }
}

public class BPlaceHolder
{
  public string NodeName { get; set; }
  public List<B> Items { get; set; }
}

public class CClassViewModel
{
    CClassModel m_model;
    public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; set; }

    public CClassViewModel()
    {
        m_model = new CClassModel();
        Items = new ObservableCollection<object>;

        APlaceHolder aph = new APlaceHolder();
        aph.NodeName = "A Items";
        aph.Items = m_model.m_ItemsA;
        Items.Add(aph);

        BPlaceHolder bph = new BPlaceHolder();
        bph.NodeName = "B Items";
        bph.Items = m_model.m_ItemsB;
        Items.Add(bph);
    }
}
```

You need to add HierarchicalDataTemplates for APlaceHolder and BPlaceHolder, and DataTemplates for A and B.